# Solve equation: $\log_2 \left(1+ \frac{1}{a}\right) + \log_2 \left(1 +\frac{1}{b}\right)+ \log_2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{c}\right) = 2$

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

$$
\log_2 \left(1  + \frac{1}{a}\right) + \log_2 \left(1  + \frac{1}{b}\right)+ \log_2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{c}\right) = 2 \quad \text{where $a$, $b$, $c \in N$.}
$$

Apparently, the answer is $a= 1$, $b =2$, and $c\space = 3$.

When I asked my math teacher I was told that the solution involved a bit of number theory, but didn't recieve a complete explanation.
Could someone clear that up for me?

Edit: I had made a mistake in typing the question. I had left it as:

$
\log_2 \left(a  + \frac{1}{a}\right) + \log_2 \left(b  + \frac{1}{b}\right)+ \log_2 \left(c + \frac{1}{c}\right) = 2 \quad \text{where $a$, $b$, $c \in N$.}
$

My apologies for causing confusion.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the equation does *not* hold for $(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)$. Perhaps it is $\log_2 (1  + \frac{1}{a}) + \log_2 (1  + \frac{1}{b})+ \log_2 (1  + \frac{1}{c}) = 2$? In that case you can find a solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h43200p273208.

Comment: Yes, Indeed it is, I made a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out and sharing the link!

Comment: After your edit, you put Ishan's answer, with a decent amount of upvotes, in an unfavorable light. Also, the title still points at the old version.

Comment: @rtybase: On the other hand, if a question states that *“apparently, the answer is ...”* if it isn't then a request for clarification might be more appropriate than answering the (apparently wrong) question.

Comment: @MartinR indeed, I was just highlighting the fact. I hope guys will find a way to sort this little problem out. I'd simply add notes in the question and answer mentioning the edit (and time of the edit) and the change in the meaning of the question. Or close this one and create another ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, as you have written it, has no solution.

Simplifying the LHS, we get $$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1) = 4abc$$
But, by the AM-GM inequality, we get $x^2+1\ge2x$, which gives 
$$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1) \ge 8abc$$

Comment: I am so sorry. I made a mistake in typing out the question. Sincere apologies.

Comment: @Apologies are fine...but not enough in this case. You have here a very nice answer and with clear explanations and you **should** leave the original question as it was, and *then ask a new question* ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio True, I hadn't thought of doing that. But I don't want to create any more confusion by editing the question back to what it was. I will be sure to do what you have suggested in case I make a similar mistake in the future.